# Where is CRT in generated manifest for VC10?

Tags: visual-c++

I use Visual Studio 2010 Premium for create test binary console application project.
I use:

- Functions from C-runtime like feof, getchar
- Use Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)Code generation mode

But in output generated manifest I'm only receive this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

I want to force client use only version of CRT on which the application was built. And use for it 
SxS feature.

Q1: How I can I append this version info to manifest ?
I don't see any *.manifest templates in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\"

Q2: Is it possible to view %windir%\winsxs with some tool like gacutil for .net ?

Comment: These feature was discontinued in VS2010, too many complaints about it.

Comment: Can you say smth. about Q2?